# Retrieve $_GET properties in a single statement

Tags: php, get

Currently, I check to see if a `$_GET` or `$_POST` property is set by using `empty()`. Like this:

```
$status = null;

if (!empty($_GET['foo'])) {
    $status = $_GET['foo'];
}
```

I imagine there is an even more concise way of doing the same thing built into PHP, that like what I'm doing now with `empty`, also avoids printing the notice saying undefined index. Maybe something like this:

```
$status = something($_GET['foo']);
```

Or, maybe I should just ignore the notice and do:

```
$status = $_GET['foo'];
```

Comment: `empty()` does not get you a notice, see the manual: `empty() does not generate a warning if the variable does not exist.`.

Comment: $status = !empty($_GET['foo']) ? $_GET['foo'] : null;

Comment: just to clarify, i am currently using `empty` because it does not give me the notice. i want something more compact that does not give me the notice too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what the problem is as [`empty()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php) does not generate a warning for undefined variables, but if you want it in one line, you can use a ternary expression:

```
$status = empty($_GET['foo']) ? null : $_GET['foo'];
```

Comment: i meant that *also* does not print notices. the reason im using empty now is because it does not. i want something more compact that also does not. sorry to not be clear about that.

Comment: @tau This is about as compact as it gets.

Answer (score 0):

How about this if you want just GET:

```
$status = isset($_GET['foo'])?$_GET['foo']:NULL;
```

Or this if you want just GET and POST:

```
$status = isset($_GET['foo'])?$_GET['foo']:(isset($_POST['foo'])?NULL);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can always check if the key in the $_GET array exists and set the variable to null if it isn't. Will never throw a notive.

```
$status = array_key_exists('foo', $_GET) ? $_GET['foo'] : null;
```

Answer (score -2):

You can suppress the warnings by using @.

```
$status = @$_GET['foo'];
```